# payara.fish app server jelastic support

Tags: glassfish, jelastic, payara

is possible to add support for the [payara.fish](http://www.payara.fish/) application server by cartridges ?

> Payara Server is a drop in replacement for GlassFish Server Open Source Edition, with the peace of mind of quarterly releases containing enhancements, bug fixes and patches.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We recommend you our Docker with Payara.

1. Copy this [link](https://download.jelastic.com/public.php?service=files&t=60482221b67793c6d0ae319f98bdc63f&download)
2. Go to New environment - Import

[image: import]

3. Choose URL tab, paste the link and press Import

[image]

4. Specify the name, choose the region and press Install

[image]

5. Your Payara will be running in a few minutes

[image]

Comment: i use trail account, jelastic v4.2 and don`t have that options - New environment - Import, only create. also searched in marketplace, but there no jelastic/payara-full, only jelastic/payara-micro

Comment: You can contact you hosting provider in order to get this option enabled in trial for testing and then upgrade your account.

Comment: Or get trial with our partner from Sweden https://jelastic.cloud/details/elastx (they have a trial with import-export enabled)

Comment: ok, now import option is enabled, but i get the error {"result":11015,"error":"Unknown JPS version!","source":"marketplace"} used this [link](https://download.jelastic.com/public.php?service=files&t=60482221b67793c6d0ae319f98bdc63f&download) in the URL tab

Comment: Please, try one more time with this link https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jelastic/payara/master/payara-server-full/manifest.jps